# How to add owners for Microsoft App in registration portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have registered an app in Microsoft App registration portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) using my personal outlook id. I have used the same App id and password to create Webapp bot in Azure portal under my enterprise login. Now I want to transfer the ownership of the application to my enterprise email, but i don't have any option for that.

How can I transfer the ownership from my personal outlook id to enterprise id.

Answer (score 4):

Even though you are creating the application using a liveID , the application object is always getting created within an azure active directory instance. You may not be able to move this application object from one directory to another and you would have to register a new one again with the same parameters. If it is a multi tenant application , then you may be able to create a service principal for this one within your company directory with your enterprise ID and provide access to it. I believe your enterprise ID and liveID are both in two different directories. I would suggest to create a new application entry if it is possible. You may have to do some changes in your infrastructure however , it may reduce the complexity in the environment .